# Why does IDataReader lose a row?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, enterprise-library

I am facing this problem. I have a stored procedure which returns 6 rows when I execute it.

But when I am retrieving the rows in my app by using `ExecuteReader`, it only returns only 5 rows. **Why is it losing a row??**

My stored procedure consists of 5 union statements which are getting filled from a single table:

```
 dbase.AddInParameter(cmd, "@LoginUser", DbType.String, UserID);

   try
   {
      using (IDataReader  dr = dbase.ExecuteReader(cmd))
      if (dr.Read())
      {
         dt = new DataTable("DashBoard");
         dt.Load(dr);
      }
   }
```

`dbase` is my database object. And `cmd` is the `SqlCommand` used to call the stored procedure.

`UserID` is parameter is passing

Stored procedure code is:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[USP_ViewAdminDashBoard](@LoginUser varchar(75)) 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET DATEFORMAT DMY;
    DECLARE @LastLoginDate  as DateTime

        Select @LastLoginDate = dbo.UDF_GetLastLoginByUser(@LoginUser)
    Select 'Last Login Date', convert(varchar(12),@LastLoginDate,105)

    Union 
    Select  'Nos. Records pending for Upload' as Title, convert(varchar(5),COUNT(s.BatchID)) Total from  dbo.BREGISTRATIONENTRY s, Dbo.TBL_iBATCH B
    where  B.BatchID = s.BatchID And b.Forwarded = 0 and b.isBatchClosed = 1
END
```

Comment: Please show us the stored procedure too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your first `dr.Read` is advancing to the first row. The DataTable.Load is reading the remaining rows but not the first row

Use [HasRows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.hasrows.aspx) to test for existence and don't use `Read` before the `DataTable.Load`

Edit:

Just load the DataTable without testing first: then test on the DataTable. There is no HasRows in the IDataReader interface.

Comment: Thanks Pal i miss the basic's

Comment: Unfortunately, `IDataReader` does not have `HasRows`, so I guess you can just create the `DataTable` and check if the result has rows instead.

Comment: Yes i did the same.but suppose if reader fails to get data.then at the time of checking Datatable it gives the error that DR is null but why dont know

Comment: @Madhav: you have to work with what they give you: and you can't test the DR first...

Answer (score 0):

IDataReader is a forward reader,it means when you read a row,that row will be deleted from the reader and you can't get it from the reader any more.

Answer (score 0):

joshua i also has this problem while using enterprise library more than two time even i use same code written down but both time i found a problem in my store procedure there must be any wrong selection in query or any think else which db server does not detect and i solve it and 
my IDataReader select all rows and also use same way as suggest by 'gbn' 
  using (IDataReader dr = oDb.ExecuteReader(p_oDbCommand))
                {

```
                if (dr != null)
                {

                   ds.Tables[0].Load(dr);
                }

            }
            return dt;
```